# ROS Answers SE migration: listener.cpp

Tags: ros, roscpp, ros-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello..
Am at tutorial: Examine simple Publisher and Subscriber.

On command: **rosrun beginner_tutorials talker** I get proper out "hello world" 233 (so on..)
but for command: **rosrun begineer_tutorials listener**

There is nothing displayed on the terminal:

its just blank **~/ros workspace/beginner_tutorials$** ***(nothing)***

i have re-done file listener.cpp
updated Cmakelist.txt, am I suppose to do any other changes??

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12343/listener.cpp/) by [dbs12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1469/dbs12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I just tested it. Its working fine.
Just check if both talker and listener are connected through the same topic "/chatter"

You can use below command to do that.

```
rxgraph
```

The graph should look exactly like below. If both are not connected then it means you are publishing and advertising in different topics.
[image: image description]

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3